# UINavigationBar Custom Title View not centered on iOS11

Tags: ios11, xcode9.1

I just updated to Xcode 9 and run to an iOS11 simulator. My custom view for the navaagation bar title is shifted down.

[image]

This code was working before i updated; it was vertically centered before

```
companyCountryView = CompanyNameView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Utils.getScreenWidth() - 150, height: 35))
companyCountryView.companyLbl.text = ""
companyCountryView.countryLbl.text = ""
self.navigationItem.titleView = companyCountryView
```

Even though I change values for y and height, no effect at all.
It seems the width value i used does not do any effect too.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! You need to override the intrinsicContentSize in your custom view class and put the size of the view there:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: Utils.getScreenWidth() - 150.0, height: 35.0)
    }
}
```